# How to cheat the windows Browse dialog?

Tags: c#, silverlight, debugging, testing, dialog

I have an application where i use the windows browse dialog to select a file from the file system. The application is written in C#, silverlight. My requirement is that when i select any particular file from this dialog, the user should be restricted to selecting only a set of files with a particular extension. I have achieved this and the dialog only lists those files with the extension i permit. I am trying to break this by somehow letting the user select a file with a different extension from what is permitted. Is there a way to select a file from this dialog other than the one which is permitted ? Any user hacks ?

PS: i dont want to change any code. I need this only for testing purpose with an intention to break the functionality.

Comment: Why not just assume that it is breakable (even if you can't do it) and  put code in that checks the extension after selection?

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple way: The user can just type `*.*` into the file name box and he will see all files.